# Show that if $(X, \mathcal{T}), (Y, \mathcal{J})$ are both metrizable, then $X \times Y$ with product topology is metrizable

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification, metric-spaces, proof-writing

Let $(X, \mathcal{T}), (Y, \mathcal{J})$ be both metrizable, then

> Claim: $X \times Y$ with product topology is metrizable

I have made an attempt at this question but the notation is overwhelmingly messy and I can't see how I could produce an actual metric

---

**Proof attempt:**

- Let $d$ be the metric on $X$ that generates $\mathcal{T}$, and $\rho$
  be the metric on $Y$ that generates $\mathcal{J}$.

  Then given $X \times Y$ with the product topology generated by the
  basis $\mathcal{T} \times \mathcal{J}$, we wish to show there exists
  some metric that generates the product topology on $X \times Y$.

  We know that $B_d = \{B^d_\epsilon(x)| x \in X, \epsilon > 0\}$ is a
  basis on $X$ generating $\mathcal{T}$

  And  $B_\rho = \{B^{\rho}_\delta(y)| y \in Y, \delta > 0\}$ is a
  basis on $Y$ generating $\mathcal{J}$.

  Take $U\in \mathcal{T}$, and $V \in \mathcal{J}$ Then $\forall x \in
     X, y \in Y, (x,y) \in U \times V, \exists \epsilon, \delta > 0$ such
  that $B^d_\epsilon(x) \times B^{\rho}_\delta(y) \subseteq U  \times 
     V$

  Furthermore, $\forall (x,y) \in X \times Y, (x,y) \in$ $B^d_\epsilon(x) \times B^{\rho}_\delta(y)$, for some $\delta, \epsilon >0$. That is $B_d \times B_\rho$  covers $X\times Y$.

  Therefore $B_d \times B_\rho$ is a basis in terms of metric balls
  that generates the product topology on $X \times Y$...

  ... So $X \times Y$ is metrizable.

---

**Question:**

1. Since I am working with basis, is it necessary to show the inclusion the other way i.e. $\mathcal{T} \times \mathcal{J} \subseteq B_d \times B_\rho$
2. I failed to produce an actual function...and a space is metrizable if there exists a distance function that generates its topology. How do I fix this situation?

Comment: why don't you take $\gamma((x_1,y_1),(x_2,y_2))=\delta(x_1,x_2)+\rho(y_1,y_2)$ ?

Comment: @CarryonSmiling Hmm not sure if that works, but it looks like it will

Comment: Tell me if you need help proving it works.

Comment: @BeachedWhale: It’s also quite easy to work with the product metric $$\gamma(\langle x_1,y_1\rangle,\langle x_2,y_2\rangle)=\max\{\delta(x_1,x_2),\rho(y_1,y_2)\}\;.$$